# Unable to render simple component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I wish to import and render a simple component into a **.js** file. When I navigate to the `StatusScreen` page, I expect to view the text: '**I'm a Card**', however, I get the error message:

> text strings must be rendered within a text component.

I have copied most of this code from a video tutorial, and am unsure why I am unable to render components after importing them.

**testcard.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions,Image,ImageBackground,Pressable} from 'react-native';
import {
    responsiveHeight,
    responsiveWidth,
    responsiveFontSize
  } from "react-native-responsive-dimensions";

export const Card = () => {
    return <div>I'm a Card</div>

};
```

**StatusScreen.js**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState, useEffect }from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions,Image,ImageBackground,Pressable} from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {
  responsiveHeight,
  responsiveWidth,
  responsiveFontSize
} from "react-native-responsive-dimensions";
import { shouldUseActivityState } from 'react-native-screens';
import moment from 'moment';
import {Clock} from './clock';
import { Card } from './testcard';


export default class StatusScreen extends React.Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            headerShown: false
        };
    };

    render() {

        const { navigate, state } = this.props.navigation;
        
        return (
            <div className='StatusScreen'> <Card/></div>
        );

    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#8b1538',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    start: {
      //color: '#fff'
      borderRadius: 4,
     // elevation: 3,
      backgroundColor: 'black',
      height: responsiveHeight(10), // 50% of window height
      width: responsiveWidth(40), // 50% of window width
      left: responsiveWidth(30),
      top: responsiveHeight(80),
      opacity: 0
    },
    testtext: {
      left: responsiveWidth(30),
      top: responsiveHeight(80),
    },
  });
```

I must admit that I am very new to react native, and do fully understand the fundamentals/jargon.

Comment: you cannot use div and classnames in react native.. its used to build we apps.. you can use View instead of div in react native check this for more https://reactnative.dev/docs/components-and-apis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div>`'s are used for webpages, so the "normal" version of react. But for react-native, you need to use react-native's components instead, the main ones being `<View>` (which roughly corresponds to a `<div>`) and `<Text>` (which roughly corresponds to a `<p>`). Strings can only be put on the screen by putting it inside a `<Text>`.

So your card component should look like this:

```
export const Card = () => {
   return <Text>I'm a Card</Text>
};
```

And your status screen would return something like this:

```
return (
  <View><Card/></View>
);
```

Comment: That clarifies some things! unfortunately, the error message still persists after reloading the app in my emulator.

Comment: Then apparently you have additional spots in your code where you've got a string that isn't inside a `<Text>`. Be aware: while whitespace at the beginning and ends of lines are ignored, white space in the middle of a line is treated as a space, and so may cause the error you're seeing. So for example, `<View> </View>` on a single line with a space in between could cause this.